# Crystal Report corruption

Tags: crystal-reports

Unsure if anyone on here could lend a hand, but I thought I'd give it a shot. Google wasn't too useful.

I have a report that I was working on all yesterday in Crystal Reports XI. I thought it was all good and working, so I closed the file (big mistake). Now, I try and open it again, and it's not letting me.

I get the following errors:

> "An Ole object in this report could
>   not not be loaded. It has been
>   replaced with a blank object"

So then crystal tries to load my report with it's changes (I think), and then I get:

> " This document could not
>   be opened. It does not appear to be a
>   Crystal Report document. This document
>   has the expected file extension
>   (.RPT), but it seems to be corrupted.
>   If this report used to work, try
>   opening it with a different version of
>   Crystal reports and if that still does
>   not work, please contact your
>   administrator".

I don't have another version of Crystal to check it with, and I'm pretty much the local admin for crystal, and I have no idea what to do.

Crystal wasn't letting me save over previous versions of this report yesterday, and now none of the 6+ versions I have are loading.

Can anyone suggest anything to help?

Comment: out of curiosity, what type of ole object was it? I've crashed crystal many a times trying to add various ole objects.

Comment: Hi dotjoe, I have no idea. It may have been one of the suppression conditionals, or even one of the textfields, but on recreating it nothing failed, so I'm none the wiser as to why it happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got around this error by recreating the entire report.

I have no idea what the issue was, but after I spend 2 hours recreating it, it now works as intended.

I'm guessing that if anyone else receives the terminal Corruption error, they should just throw it away and start again.

Answer (score 0):

You can try opening it in Visual Studio, which may or may not have the same version of Crystal.  But it's a binary file, and if that gets munched, I'm not sure you have much recourse.

Comment: I don't have access to Visual Studio. I'm trying to determine if it is a problem with all reports, not just this particular one.

Comment: Gah! I think it was an issue with some of the suppression functions I had. I have recreated the basic report and it's working at the moment -_-